# ko is not defined error durandal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, module, durandal

I'm new with durandal. I was trying to add a new module into the demo app provided by durandal using mimosa skelton.

I created the module followings steps in [this](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module/)

When I run the app I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to load routed module (viewmodels/myPage). Details: ko is not defined
```

my module backend.js

```
define(function(require){
  return {
    getCustomers:function(){
      //do some ajax and return a promise
        return $.ajax({
          url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?',
          dataType: 'json',
        }).promise();
    }
  };
});
```

my myPage.js

```
define(function (require) {
    var backend = require('backend');

    return {
        customer:ko.observable(),
        activate:function(){
          var that = this;
          return backend.getCustomers().then(function(result){
            that.customer(result);
          });
        }
      };
});
```

myPage.html

```
<h1>Getting facebook fan page details using jquery</h1>
<p id="cover-page"></p>
<table class="zebra-style">
    <tr><td>Name </td><td><p class="facebook_name" data-bind="html:name"></p></td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td>About </td><td><p class="facebook_about"></p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>No of Likes </td><td><p class="facebook_likes"></p></td></tr>
    <tr  class="odd"><td>Website </td><td><p class="facebook_website"></p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Category </td><td><p class="facebook_category"></p></td></tr>
    <tr class="odd"><td>Founded </td><td><p class="facebook_founded"></p></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Fan Page Url </td><td><p class="facebook_link"></p></td></tr>
    <tr  class="odd"><td>People Talking About Your Page </td><td><p class="facebook_talk_count"></p></td></tr>
</table>
```

What did I do wrong? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Durandal 2.0 Knockout is no longer a global dependency but loaded through RequireJs.

So you need to call `var ko = require('knockout');` in your module to make Knockout available:

```
define(function (require) {
    var backend = require('backend');
    var ko = require('knockout');

    return {
        customer:ko.observable(),
        activate:function(){
          var that = this;
          return backend.getCustomers().then(function(result){
            that.customer(result);
          });
        }
      };
});
```

Comment: could you guide me to prepare the html?

Comment: Got this in terminal: Dependency [[ knockout ]], inside file [[ /home/local/user/Documents/Durandal/durandal_mimosa/public/javascripts/app/viewmodels/myPage.js ]], cannot be found.

Comment: Does you require.js config includeds knockout in your main.js: `requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        ...
        'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0',
        ...
    }
});`

Comment: Another doubt: how to map it to the html I have included html file in the question

Answer (score 1):

`ko` inside myPage.js is used without telling require that it's needed.
Using the same common.js syntax as above and assuming that you've a path defined for `knockout` this the dependency is declared.

```
define(function (require) {
    var backend = require('backend');
    var ko = require('knockout');

    return {
        customer:ko.observable(),
        activate:function(){
          var that = this;
          return backend.getCustomers().then(function(result){
            that.customer(result);
          });
        }
      };
});
```

While AMD handling of jquery is slightly different it would be consistent to define the  jquery dependency in backend.js as well.

```
define(function(require){
  var $ = require('jquery');

  return {
    getCustomers:function(){
      //do some ajax and return a promise
        return $.ajax({
          url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/facebook?callback=?',
          dataType: 'json',
        }).promise();
    }
  };
});
```

Just to add: Instead of the above common.js syntax the default AMD syntax also is often used within Durandal application. Both are equivalent and it's a question of personal style which gets used.

```
define(['backend', 'knockout'], function (backend, ko) {

 return {
    customer:ko.observable(),
    activate:function(){
      var that = this;
      return backend.getCustomers().then(function(result){
        that.customer(result);
      });
    }
  };
});
```